# How to break 'if' statement in java.?

Tags: java

In the following code. I want to execute only first if statement.
While executing it is displaying output,
Valid
try again.
I want it, to print only 'valid' NOT to display 'try again'.
How to do in java.?? I am a beginner.

```
public class Test {
    public void validate(int age) {
        if (age >= 18) {
            System.out.println("Valid.");
        }
        if (age < 18) {
            System.out.println("Not valid.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("try again.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.validate(18);
    }
}
```

Comment: **`else`** `if (age < 18)`. This is a good starting point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
public void validate(int age) {
    if (age >= 18) {
        System.out.println("Valid.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not valid.");
        System.out.println("Try again.");
    }
}
```

Explanation: The first `if` only prints a text if the age is at least 18, but that has nothing to do with the following lines. Those act on their own and have two cases: either the user is below 18 or the "try again" text is displayed.

What you want to do is to check "is the age at least 18?" (as you already do) and then display either "valid" or "invalid". Do this by adding the `else` case to this check, and you are fine.

**EDIT:** I appended the second line to the `else` case due to the second comment that I understand as "I need the second message to be displayed but only in case the age is invalid".

Comment: I want that. If 1 codtn is true. it should not check other 'if or 'else' statements. How to do it.??

Comment: The above does that. It *only* executes the `else` statement if the first condition is not true. That means it only does ONE of those two things: display "valid" or display "invalid".

Comment: I want to do it using multi-if statements. If first statement is true. It should come out of the condtn. w/o displaying anything xcept valid statement condtn.

Comment: That's exactly what it will do.  Seriously, your example doen't make a lot of sense.  Any number that is not greater or equal to 18 is less than 18.  And vice versa.

Comment: This looks like the right answer to me. @ManisshKhaparde If you are not happy with it maybe it would be better to explain in plain English in your question what the `validates` method is supposed to do. You could add a `return` in your first if but that would still no be better than this answer (actually worse)

Comment: I also thought of `return` but I interpreted it as "skipping the second if" = "In case the age is valid, the second println should not occur, but I still need it in the else case". @ManisshKhaparde see the updated code above, does that fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void validate(int age) {
        if (age >= 18) {
            System.out.println("Valid.");
        } else if (age < 18) {
            System.out.println("Not valid.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("try again.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.validate(18);
    }
```

Problem with your code was even if `age` is >=18 it will still check if it is also <18, so it will always say `try again` when `age` is >=18.
Also, please check in comments that it will never say `try again` with this corrected code because under no circumstances will `age` be not <18 and >=18 at the same time

**EDIT** I like Dennis' code better because I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You will never reach `else` statement with such conditions.

Comment: @michalk, yes, true

Comment: But it is displaying 'else' statement. i executed it.

Comment: I want that. If 1 codtn is true. it should not check other 'if or 'else' statements. & without altering the code.How to do it.??

Comment: @ManisshKhaparde This is achieved by using `else if` instead of only `if`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets get some facts about integers sorted out.

1. If an integer is >= 18, that means it is not < 18
2. If an integer is < 18, that means it is not >= 18
3. Any a number is an integer, it is either >= 18 or < 18.  It cannot be both.  It cannot be neither.

Now to your code.  I could write your method like this:

```
public void validate(int age) {
    if (age >= 18) {
        System.out.println("Valid.");
    }
    if (age < 18) {
        System.out.println("Not valid.");
    }
}
```

or more simply (relying on the above facts)

```
public void validate(int age) {
    if (age >= 18) {
        System.out.println("Valid.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not valid.");
    }
}
```

That will write either `Valid` or `Not Valid`.

I could also write the code like this:

```
   public void validate(int age) {
        if (age >= 18) {
            System.out.println("Valid.");
            return;
        }
        if (age < 18) {
            System.out.println("Not valid.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("try again.");
        }
    }
```

but the `else` part is redundant because of the above mentioned facts about numbers.  Notice how I used a `return` to "break" the control flow.

You can't use a `break` statement in this context.  The Java Language Specification states in [JLS 14.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

For an unlabelled `break` statement:

> *"If no switch, while, do, or for statement in the immediately enclosing method, constructor, or initializer contains the break statement, a compile-time error occurs."*

We don't have `switch`, `while`, `do` or `for` statement here.

For a labelled break, the JLS says.

> "*A break statement must refer to a label within the immediately enclosing method, constructor, initializer, or lambda body. There are no non-local jumps. If no labeled statement with Identifier as its label in the immediately enclosing method, constructor, initializer, or lambda body contains the break statement, a compile-time error occurs.*"

... so I suppose it would be possible to write this:

```
   public void validate(int age) {
       label: { 
           if (age >= 18) {
               System.out.println("Valid.");
               break label;
           }
           if (age < 18) {
               System.out.println("Not valid.");
           } else {
               System.out.println("try again.");
           }
       }
   }
```

But frankly, that is horrible.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. "return' and 'label' only works in this. Thnx a lot.